# JSON format ASP.NET webforms

Tags: asp.net

I am new to JSON and when I am looking at the format of the message, I am getting something like below.

```
[{"id":"000078","Name":"-Name not listed-","Column1":"","Column2":"","Column3":"","city":"","lname":"Unknown"},{"id":"00139800181","Name":"Sample Name (office address, Henderson)","Column1":"office address","Column2":"","Column3":"","city":"Henderson","lname":"Clear"}]
```

the following is my code to generate the above message

```
 Dim serializer As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
 Dim rows As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))()
 Dim row As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
 For Each dr As DataRow In datatable.Rows
     row = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
     For Each col As DataColumn In datatable.Columns
        row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr(col))
     Next
        rows.Add(row)
     Next

 Dim json As String = serializer.Serialize(rows)
 Return json
```

I am using ASP.NET  4.0 but when I have looked at some of the forms, I should be receiving JSON format as below.

```
{"d":[{"id":"000078","Name":"-Name not listed-","Column1":"","Column2":"","Column3":"","city":"","lname":"Unknown"},{"id":"00139800181","Name":"Sample Name (office address, Henderson)","Column1":"office address","Column2":"","Column3":"","city":"Henderson","lname":"Clear"}]}
```

not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would [format your JSON](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) prior to posting it, as it would increase readability and make it easier for people to answer.

Comment: What consumes this JSON?

Comment: my Ajax jquery script will consume this.

Comment: So how did you come up with the idea of the format?

Comment: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx/ after seeing this forum.

Comment: from ASP.NET 3.5, wrapping has to be done automatically. but in my case I am not seeing that.

Comment: the "d" part is auto added by ASP.NET. So whatever JSON you receive from WebForm, it would be {"d": []}

Comment: Yeah!! but unfortunately it was not adding.